# Where can I read this book?

Tags: jewish-books, messiah

Does anyone know where I can read the following book online (preferably for free): **The Doctrine of the Messiah in Medieval Jewish Literature** (Authored by: Joseph Sarachek)

If not, can anyone **recommend a similar** book which I can read online (preferable for free also).

Many thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can read the book in its entirety [here](https://archive.org/details/doctrineofmessia0000sara) on the Internet Archive. You basically create an account for free and then you can borrow it like you would with an online library.

Alternatively, a lot of it is accessible on Google Books [here](https://archive.org/details/doctrineofmessia0000sara).